# Putting your Application on sale

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, purchase-order

I can't seem to find the information on this anywhere and wouldn't put it on SO if I did. So just wanted to know something. I'm releasing my very first android app on Thursday and want to put it on sale for the first two days. Is there a way you can do that? And thank you for reading this. I'm learning everyday thanks to SO.

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138412?hl=en

Comment: Thank you very much @Anoop. Would you like to put it as an answer so I can accept it :)? Just wanted to make sure I knew how to do it before I released it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you do not put it for free, as you won't be able to charge for the app later even if you wanted to.In that case you would have to release a new app with a new package name.

[Get more details here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138412?hl=en)

Also to know about minimum you can charge, [click here.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3541286)

Comment: Beyond amazing with the information!! Thank you Anoop!